# Is my transit at FRA to Amsterdam domestic or international?

Tags: air-travel, schengen, customs-and-immigration, fra

I'm traveling to Amsterdam from Oslo via Frankfurt. I have a single entry Schengen visa and Oslo will be the first point for me to enter the EU area. When I arrive in Frankfurt, should I go to the area for international flights, or should I go to the domestic flights area? Since I'll be travelling within the EU, will I go through passport control in Frankfurt?

Comment: @pnut Norway divides its airports into three parts---domestic, Schengen, and other international. However it is unusual for there to be an ID check between the domestic and Schengen areas, although in principle it is a customs border. This is a bit different from EU states who don't tend to distinguish between domestic & Schengen flights.

Comment: @pnuts A flight from Oslo to Frankfurt is deemed international, but not subject to immigration control. I regularly fly from Oslo to other Schengen countries and have never experienced an official id control leaving Norway and as far as I know, there are no facilities at the airport allowing such control without in practice halting regular operations. *If* there had been an offical id check, you would however not have been 'stamped out' of the Schengen area.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo indeed, the Schengen codes use the useful term "internal" to refer to intra-Schengen flights, the bulk of which are of course, strictly speaking, international. I have on occasion advocated for the use of this term on this site, but as others have rightly pointed out, insisting on precise terminology may not be very helpful to casual users who are infrequent travelers and who therefore don't have a very thorough understanding of the situation.  When I was flying weekly between AMS and Oslo, we would frequently be checked (not stamped) at the gate on arrival in Oslo.

Comment: @pnuts in the three-part division of (1) domestic, (2) Schengen, (3) other international, a flight to Frankfurt would come under (2) Schengen, and would therefore be classified neither as domestic nor as "other international."  Flights between Schengen countries ("internal" flights) are international, strictly speaking, even though passengers are not subjected to immigration controls.

Comment: @phoog But it is especially for flights to, from and between the Schengen countries, which are not in the EU (Iceland, Norway and Switzerland) IMHO just as misleading and incorrect to call them 'domestic' flights as you are e.g. subject to much stricter customs regulations, as if you are flying between EU states.

Comment: @pnuts the middle q?  Which one is that?  I see only two `?` characters in the body of the question.  Anyway, the question is asking about a flight *from* Frankfurt to Amsterdam, whereas your comment seems to concern a flight *to* Frankfurt (from Oslo).  And the literal answer probably *is* "neither," not least because there is no "domestic" area in FRA.  But the real answer is what Henning Makholm said: Don't worry about that, just determine the gate for your flight and follow the signs directing you to that gate.

Comment: @phoog I would agree that "internal" makes a lot more sense than "domestic".

Answer (score 20):

You are correct that Norway is not in the EU -- but what matters for passport control is not EU membership, but *Schengen*, and Norway **is** in the Schengen area. So both your flights will be Schengen-internal.

In Frankfurt, when you get off your plane just follow the "connecting flights" signs until you reach an area where you see monitors showing lists of departing flights. Then locate your outgoing flight on the monitors and follow the signage towards the gate displayed for it.

Following the correct signs should *not* lead you through an exit immigration check.

Comment: and as far as I remember, he shouldn't be able to go through exit immigration without a boarding pass anyway.

Comment: If the OP happens to get as far as Frankfurt and gets stuck, you can get a train to Amsterdam (lasts about 4 hours) from Frankfurt.

Comment: Yes. Moreover, this advice holds even for flight origins outside of Schengen: say, on NYC-FRA-AMS, the FRA-AMS boarding pass will have a terminal number (if not a gate), and following the signs to that terminal will correctly lead you to the right immigration stuff.

Answer (score 9):

Frankfurt airport is *not* separated into a ‘domestic’ and an ‘international’ area. Rather, the flights are allocated a gate and the gate number includes a letter for the area (A, B or C in terminal 1, D or E in termainal 2). Memorise the *area* that your gate is in and proceed there.

Once you have reached the area, signs will show you different directions for the gate numbers.

You should not encounter any immigration control on your way as all three airports in question (Oslo, Amsterdam and Frankfurt) are part of the Schengen area (as other answers have mentioned).

Comment: But there are Schengen and non Schengen areas. Also transferring from one terminal to an other, you have separated wagons.

Comment: I like this answer best as it makes it clear that the domestic/international distinction is obsolete in the Schengen area. This is true for all airports I have seen in the area.

Comment: @Calimo Even when only considering the airports relevant for this question, it is not true. The airport in Oslo is separated in domestic and international areas and the international area is again separated in Schengen- and Non-Schengen areas.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Yes, but they are not *labelled* as Schengen/non-Schengen. The distinction is purely by gate area (B being non-Schengen in terminal 1, iirc).

Answer (score -1):

No, you will not go thru passport control in Frankfurt. It's actually a domestic flight.

Comment: I don't really see what this adds to the existing answers.

Comment: Oslo, Frankfurt and Amsterdam are in all different countries. None of the flights between them are domestic.